# MySQL - select inside select and use NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables:

```
WORKERS(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text, Phone text, Age integer, Dapartment 
text)

Dapartments(Name text, Manger text)
```

And I want to get the name of an employee who has only one manager, I guess there are a total of 2 managers, and each employee can have 2 managers (at least 1).

I try to do:

```
SELECT Name, 
       Manger 
  FROM (SELECT * 
          FROM WORKERS 
               INNER JOIN Dapartments 
                  ON WORKERS.Dapartment = Dapartments.Name 
         WHERE Manger = 'manger1') 
 WHERE NOT EXSITS (SELECT * 
                     FROM WORKERS 
                         INNER JOIN Dapartments 
                            ON WORKERS.Dapartment = Dapartments.Name 
                    WHERE Manger = 'manger2');
```

And I get this error:

```
Error: near line 52: near "SELECT": syntax error
```

What is wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY , HAVING, COUNT().

Comment: How can a worker have 2 managers? Each worker belongs to 1 Department, right? And each Department has 1 manager, right? Or not?

Comment: @forpas that would be in a perfect world :) I've been in many companies where this is actually possible =/

Comment: Your query is full of typos, including "NOT EXSITS" should be "NOT EXISTS". Probably part of the problem. As long as your table names and such line up, doesn't matter if not spelled correctly, but need to get the sql keywords correct.

Comment: @JorgeCampos my comment is about the 2 tables structure. I guess the workers table has 1 row for each worker which has 1 department that the worker belongs to. This department has 1 manager in the departments table, unless there are multiple rows in the departments table for each department.

Comment: For clarity, start by adding table aliases to your table references. And use them.

Comment: What is `EXSITS`?

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results -- particularly workers with multiple managers and how they are represented in this data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You need  an table alias name for the FROM(   ) Table_name _alias ( in this sample T)

```
    SELECT T.Name, 
           T.Manger 
    FROM (
        SELECT * 
        FROM WORKERS 
        INNER JOIN Dapartments ON WORKERS.Dapartment = Dapartments.Name 
        WHERE Manger = 'manger1'
        )  T 
     WHERE NOT EXSITS (
        SELECT * 
        FROM WORKERS 
        INNER JOIN Dapartments ON WORKERS.Dapartment = Dapartments.Name 
        WHERE Manger = 'manger2'
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is below:

```
Select w.Name ,d.Manger 
    From Dapartments d
    Join Workers w
    On W.Dapartment = D.Name
Where w.id in (  
Select Id, --count(Dapartment) As Mangrs 
From WORKERS 
group by Id 
Having count(Dapartment)=1
           )
```

--- If only Worker Name is required then:

```
 Select t.Name As Single_Mgr_Worker 
From (
Select Name, count(Dapartment) As Mangrs 
From WORKERS 
group by Id 
Having count(Dapartment)=1
           ) t
```

Comment: To format your code add four extra spaces before each line :) I did it this time for you.